# How to return a byte from a byte array with the Full Hex Value?

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers, hex, byte

So I am creating a program that reads a byte array and returns the value

```
byte[] buffer1 = File.ReadAllBytes(path).Skip(startPos).Take(lengthToExtract).ToArray();
byte[] reversed = buffer1.Reverse().ToArray();
string buffer2 = "";
foreach (var i in reversed)
{
   buffer2 = buffer2 + i.ToString("X") + " ";
}
MessageBox.Show(buffer2);
int size = int.Parse(buffer2.Replace(" ", string.Empty), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
return size;
```

But when I get the message box for the value of the hex string buffer of the values it takes out the "unimportant" hex number out which messes up my value. For example if the byte read is 0x00 it will return the value as just 0, and I am reading the resulted bytes backwards so: 0x04080 (0 4 0 80) is different then 0x0040080 (00 04 00 80). I need help please this messes up my entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 functions you can use. They will solve both of the problems - double digits and bytes order

```
    public static string HexStringFromArrayChangeEndian(byte[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder sdata = new StringBuilder();
        for (int s = data.Length - 1; s >= 0; s--)
            sdata.Append(string.Format("{0:X}", data[s]).PadLeft(2, '0'));
        return sdata.ToString();
    }

    public static string HexStringFromArraySameEndian(byte[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder sdata = new StringBuilder();
        for (int s = 0; s < data.Length; s++)
            sdata.Append(string.Format("{0:X}", data[s]).PadLeft(2, '0'));
        return sdata.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Your lines with calls to `PadLeft` could be simplified to `sdata.Append(data[s].ToString("X2"));` which will prevent a bunch of extra strings being created. +1 though for using a StringBuilder to keep the garbage collector from getting angry with you.  Could take it one step further and make it `StringBuilder sdata = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 2);`

Comment: @LeeHiles Sure. Those will be some improvements

Answer (score 1):

Use `i.ToString("X2")`. Will force string output of "00" instead of simplified "0"